# Recursive method that counts the number of spaces and periods in a string

Tags: java, recursion

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to create a recursive method that counts the number of periods and spaces in a string. I can do this pretty easily using iteration, but I'm still fairly new to the concept of recursion. Here's my code so far,
could anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
public static int periodsAndSpaces(String s){ //option 3
    if(s.length()<0){ //base case
        return 0;
    }

    else if(s.charAt(0) == ' ' || s.charAt(0) == '.'){ //general case
        return periodsAndSpaces(s.substring(1)) + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well for starters, not sure how s.length() can be < 0.  It can be == to 0.

Comment: And for seconds, assuming that's all of the `periodsAndSpaces` method, it stops at the first non-period-or-space.  Thus it will tell you that `"X......    .....   "` contains 0 periods and spaces/

Comment: You need to recursively call all the way to the end regardless of the current character, while adding either 0 or 1 to the total depending on the current character.

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.test.demo;

public class Counter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Counter().countPeriodsAndSpaces(" test. . .a"));
    }

    int countPeriodsAndSpaces(String rs) {
        if (rs == null || rs.isEmpty()) 
            return 0;
        
        char c = rs.charAt(0);
        if (c == ' ' || c == '.') 
            return 1 + countPeriodsAndSpaces(rs.substring(1)); 
        else 
            return countPeriodsAndSpaces(rs.substring(1)); 
    }
    
}
```

// Output 6

Comment: You answer may be correct, but please add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

New method with everyone's suggestions:

```
public static int periodsAndSpaces(String s){ //option 3
    if(s.length()==0){ //base case
        return 0;
    }

    else if(s.charAt(0) == ' ' || s.charAt(0) == '.'){ 
        return periodsAndSpaces(s.substring(1)) + 1;
    }
    else{
        return periodsAndSpaces(s.substring(1));
    }
}
```

Method stops running when there are no more characters left in the string, and I've added another case for adding onto the sum of periods and spaces when the current char doesn't have either of these.